# How much is a bunch of spinach?

Tags: measurements, spinach

I have some recipies for green smoothies, where some of the ingredients are for example "1 bunch of spinach" or "1/2 bunch of spinach".

The spinach I've found in the store are usually fresh leaves packed in a plastic bag of for example roughly 250 grams... But, how much is a bunch?

Comment: Does your bagged spinach include leaves? (I also more frequently see bagged baby spinach than full-size spinach.)

Comment: Ack, does it include *stems*? (of course there are leaves!)

Comment: Yeah, it's a bunch of green leaves. Like, 6x4 cm in size. I'm pretty sure it's regular spinach and not baby spinach, as there are other bags which says baby spinach on them :)

Comment: @Jefromi Ah, hehe, yes, the leaves have a few cm of stems as well

Comment: But they're all separate leaves, not a single connected plant. Like a "ball of salad" or a "tree of broccoli".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bunch of spinach usually weighs something like 250-500 grams. My best guess is that something like half that is the stems, which can easily be as long as the leaves. So very roughly, I'd say a bunch is 125-250 grams. Alternately, if you want to go by volume (e.g. if your store has bulk loose baby spinach), think of a bunch as something like a head of lettuce, except with the bottom third to half mostly stems.

Full-size spinach also definitely gets a lot better than 4x6 cm leaves, so you may still be using somewhat more tender baby spinach, but that of course won't cause you any problems. (The stems on baby spinach are tender enough to eat, especially when blending, so you can use everything in your bags.)

In any case, smoothies are really forgiving - not only do you not need a lot of precision, but you can just add and blend until the color and flavor look how you want!

Comment: So 1 bunch is roughly one bag like that then, maybe  a bit less. Perfect! Thanks :) You're right that smoothies are forgiving. It's just that I'm very new, and when you don't even know what a bunch is it's a bit difficult to decide how much to use :p

Answer (score 2):

A bunch is the amount of a produce you can hold in you hand considering the picking and sales process

So for spinach, a bunch is a full handful holding the stems, you fingers do not need to touch, it just what you can hold on to comfortably

This is a very imprecise measurement

Comment: But bunches of lettuce and spinach are generally whole plants - they were *grown* until they were that size, not picked by the handful.

Comment: @Jefromi depends where you are from? A lettuce grows as a 'head', and you take a 'bunch' of lettuce leaves. A bunch of spinach (as per OP) consists of multiple heads of spinach, unless you let your spinach grow tough! I don't think a bunch is a weight type unit, it depends on the produce, and has more to do with keeping produce for sale in usable units, e.g. everything at one or two dollars. A bunch of coriander is very much smaller than a bunch of spinach, but it is the same price

Answer (score 0):

One bunch of spinach is 340 grams ( 1 cup)

Comment: Hmm, on what do you base this?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an answer more like a comment. I am now harvesting a lot of spinach. And selling per bundle. No my first dilemma was how much is a bundle. So I think of you look at the large whole leaves bundles that you buy in stores stringed at the bottom, a handful around the stems are a bundlef. One can weight that out of curiosity and see what a bundle then weights. It might come to the same answer in grams as previously discussed of 200 - 250 grams.