# How much is in a handful of spinach?

Tags: spinach, greens

Yes, I know it's a volume unit, but I want to know how many grams does a male or female handful of spinach can hold. You'll see, a recipe calls for 2 handfuls of spinach, 1 handful of parsley and 2 leaves of kale (these aren't all the ingredients, just the non-precise ingredients). So, as you can see the recipe is good for you because you don't have to measure, however, I want to get the nutritional fact of this recipe. To do this, I have to put the ingredients and its quantity on a page.

So, how much is a handful of this green veggie? Or much does it weighs? (it'll also help).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much is a bunch of spinach?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24637/how-much-is-a-bunch-of-spinach)

Comment: I used to work in a deli and when a customer told me to give a handful, it usually meant approx 200 gms. That is the amount they were looking for. So i think 200gms(a female hand)-250gms(male hand) is what you might be looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I general any recipe that uses non precise words like a "handful", is either not a well tested recipe, or the author is suggesting to use the ingredient for taste, colour, and/or texture reasons. The amount (within reason) is not critical to the recipe

Just add the amount you would like in terms of a balanced meal, and what gives the taste, colour, and/or texture you like